# React: elegant way to send click events to child component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

This sounds like an incredible basic question, I'm looking for guidance on the best pattern to follow for this problem.

An example: clicking a button an accordion will collapse it.

This seemed simple enough, just pass in an `open` prop and have the parent manage state. However this fell apart when wanting to also manage that `open` state from the child component (i.e. clicking to open/close the accordion title).

I've got two basic examples below:

### Option 1: Let child manage state, allow parent to optionally impact that state with a prop and callback.

```
const Page = () => {
    const [shouldWeHideStep1, setShouldWeHideStep1] = useState(false)

    const agreeToTerms = () => {
        // A useEffect in child component picks up this prop change, does what it needs to do, and then
        // runs our callback which will set this state variable back to false.
        // This allows us to repeat the same process over and over again.
        setShouldWeHideStep1(true)
    }

    return (
        <div>
            <Collapsible 
                openDefault={true} 
                title="Step1: Terms" 
                toggleClose={shouldWeHideStep1} 
                toggleCloseDone={() => {
                    setShouldWeHideStep1(false)
                }}>
              <div>
                  Here are the terms: etc..
                  <button onClick={agreeToTerms}>Agree and go to next step</button>
              </div>
            </Collapsible>
            <Collapsible openDefault={false} title="Step2: Something">
              <div>
                  Here is something else...
              </div>
            </Collapsible>
        </div>
    )
}

const Collapsible = ({openDefault, toggleClose = false, toggleCloseDone = null}) => {
    const [open, setOpen] = useState(openDefault)

    useEffect(() => {
        // Our parent component is sending us a one off "time to close" event.
        // We do our close thing here, update local state, then we call back to the parent
        // setState method to 
        if(toggleClose === true){
            setOpen(false)
            if(toggleCloseDone){
                toggleCloseDone()
            }
        }
    }, [toggleClose])

    const toggle = () => {
        setOpen(!open)
    }

    return (
        <div className={styles.collapsible}>
            <div className={styles.collapsibleTitle} onClick={toggle}>
                {title}
            </div>
            {open && (
                <div className={styles.collapsibleContent}>
                    {children}
                </div>
            )}
        </div>
    )
}
```

### Option 2: Remove state from child, manage it all in parent component

```
const Page = () => {
    const [step1Open, setStep1Open] = useState(true)
    const [step2Open, setStep2Open] = useState(false)

    const agreeToTerms = () => {
        setStep1Open(false)
        setStep2Open(true)
    }

    return (
        <div>
            <Collapsible
                open={step1Open}
                title="Step1: Terms"
                toggleCallback={() => {
                    setStep1Open(!step1Open)
                }}>
              <div>
                  Here are the terms: etc..
                  <button onClick={agreeToTerms}>Agree and go to next step</button>
              </div>
            </Collapsible>
            <Collapsible
                openDefault={false}
                title="Step2: Something"
                open={step2Open}
                toggleCallback={() => {
                    setStep2Open(!step2Open)
                }}>
              <div>
                  Here is something else...
              </div>
            </Collapsible>
        </div>
    )
}

const Collapsible = ({open, toggleCallback}) => {
    return (
        <div className={styles.collapsible}>
            <div className={styles.collapsibleTitle} onClick={toggleCallback}>
                {title}
            </div>
            {open && (
                <div className={styles.collapsibleContent}>
                    {children}
                </div>
            )}
        </div>
    )
}
```

What is the preferred approach for this type of problem? There's likely many more ways than the above two as well.

Comment: I like to manage in Parent. So that my child component has less dependencies. Lookig forward to other suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It always depends, but from what I see that you're trying to do, the state has to be outside the `Collapsible` component in order to allow one of the `Collapsible`'s children to modify the visibility.

Option 1 just doesn't seem right to me since you still have to have state in the parent to track when the first `Collapsible` should be hidden, and it is an odd way of managing the state.

If I have to choose between option 1 and 2, I would pick #2 with a few modifications:

- Since you want to open the next collapsible when the previous one closes, using `useReducer` would be much better for doing that synchronization and it would also allow you to add more collapsibles without creating a new state for every collapsible
- Remove unused prop `openDefault` since `open` already does that

`...`

```
const Collapsible = ({ open, toggleCallback, title, children }) => {
  // remove -- used for testing purposes
  const styles = {
    collapsibleTitle: 'test',
    title: 'test',
  };

  return (
    <div className={styles.collapsible}>
      <div className={styles.collapsibleTitle} onClick={toggleCallback}>
        {title}
      </div>
      {open && <div className={styles.collapsibleContent}>{children}</div>}
    </div>
  );
};

export const Page = () => {
  // Setting the initial visibility for all the collapsibles here
  const initialCollapsiblesVisibility = {
    step1: true,
    step2: false,
  };

  // The reducer will allow us to synchronize the collapsible components depending
  // the action that happens
  function reducer(prev, action) {
    switch (action.type) {
      // just toggle step1
      case 'toggle1': {
        return {
          ...prev,
          step1: !prev.step1,
        };
      }
      // just toggle step2
      case 'toggle2': {
        return {
          ...prev,
          step2: !prev.step2,
        };
      }

      // When we agree to terms, open collapsible2
      case 'agree1': {
        return {
          step1: false,
          step2: true,
        };
      }
      default: {
        throw Error('Unknown action: ' + action.type);
      }
    }
    
  }

  const [stepsVisibility, setStepsVisibility] = useReducer(reducer, initialCollapsiblesVisibility);

  return (
    <div>
      <Collapsible
        open={stepsVisibility.step1}
        title="Step1: Terms"
        toggleCallback={() => {
          setStepsVisibility({ type: 'toggle1' });
        }}
      >
        <div>
          Here are the terms: etc..
          <button onClick={() => setStepsVisibility({ type: 'agree1' })}>Agree and go to next step</button>
        </div>
      </Collapsible>
      <Collapsible
        openDefault={false}
        title="Step2: Something"
        open={stepsVisibility.step2}
        toggleCallback={() => {
          setStepsVisibility({ type: 'toggle2' });
        }}
      >
        <div>Here is something else...</div>
      </Collapsible>
    </div>
  );
};
```

Comment: Thank you, this was incredibly helpful. I haven't used `useReducer` before and I love this approach.